# Asp.net database table relationships

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling, foreign-key-relationship

I am looking at a way to establish a few tables in my database.

I want to connect every user that logs in to the comments that they leave. There should be 2 or 3 tables.  But I have no understanding on how to achieve this. Does anyone know where I can read and learn about how to build table relationships effectively?

Comment: that should very easy , define the tables and use normalization techqiques and get it done , if you wan the code , let us know

Comment: i draw 4 tables: 1) UserID 2)Threads 3)Comments 4)Comment Response. but i am afraid if i try to connect between them all , i will screw the relationships up. cause i am inexperiences with table relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a walk-through for SQL Server 2005: http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2007/10/basics-of-sql-server-2005.html

Comment: i need explanation on how to establish tables effectively.. one to one relationships and one to many and many to many.. thanks for the link. if i could have another link. i would be grateful

Answer (score 2):

You should understand how 'joins' work.  They will define how you access your data later.

Check out this site:
http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp

Even if you don't have MS Access, this is a good tutorial for getting a handle on creating tables and defining relationships.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/design-tables-for-a-new-access-2007-database-RZ010286445.aspx

Also, "SQL for Dummies" is a great reference to have.  Get a used copy on Amazon.